# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' when using readFileSync

Tags: typescript, npm

I am trying to read a file from typescript and I'm using 'fs' module.

```
import { readFileSync } from 'fs'
import fs from 'fs'

const fetchSavedCards = (): string[] => {
    fs.readFileSync('saved-card-details.txt','utf8');
    ...

};
```

Following error is given when building the project.

> ERROR in ./service/Service.ts
>       Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/project_path/front-end/src/service'
>        @ ./service/Service.ts 1:0-34 29:15-27
>        @ ./component/body/cart/Cart.tsx
>        @ ./component/body/Body.tsx
>        @ ./App.tsx
>        @ ./index.tsx
>       Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
>            1 asset
>           Entrypoint undefined = index.html
>           [0] ../node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./index.html 412 bytes {0} [built]
>               + 3 hidden modules
>       Child mini-css-extract-plugin ../node_modules/css-loader/index.js!../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css:
>           Entrypoint mini-css-extract-plugin = *
>              2 modules
>       Child mini-css-extract-plugin ../node_modules/css-loader/index.js!../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css:
>           Entrypoint mini-css-extract-plugin = *
>              2 modules
>       Child mini-css-extract-plugin ../node_modules/css-loader/index.js!css/site.css:
>           Entrypoint mini-css-extract-plugin = *
>           [0] ../node_modules/css-loader!./css/site.css 1.89 KiB {0} [built]
>               + 1 hidden module
>       npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>       npm ERR! errno 2
>       npm ERR! front-end@1.0.0 build: `webpack --mode production && mkdir -p ../proxy/src/main/resources/static && rm -rf ../proxy/src/main/resources/static && rm -rf ../proxy/src/main/resources/templates && mkdir -p ../proxy/src/main/resources/templates  && mv dist/index.html ../proxy/src/main/resources/templates/index.html && mv dist/ ../proxy/src/main/resources/static`
>       npm ERR! Exit status 2
>       npm ERR! 
>       npm ERR! Failed at the front-end@1.0.0 build script.
>       npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ruchira/.npm/_logs/2020-03-11T03_49_13_767Z-debug.log

My package.json file has 'fs' dependency added.

```
    "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.9.4",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.2",
    "@types/enzyme": "^3.10.5",
    "@types/enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.0.6",
    "@types/i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^2.0.2",
    "@types/i18next-xhr-backend": "^1.4.2",
    "@types/react-i18next": "^8.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.5",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.4.4",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.8",
    "file-system": "^2.2.2",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "i18next": "^13.1.5",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^2.2.4",
    "i18next-xhr-backend": "^1.5.1",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "line-reader": "^0.4.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.4.1",
    "mobx": "^5.15.4",
    "mobx-react": "^5.4.4",
    "react": "^16.13.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.0",
    "react-i18next": "^8.4.0",
    "react-icons": "^3.9.0",
    "react-popup": "^0.9.3",
    "react-router": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1"
  }
```

NPM version: 6.14.2
Node version: 11.9.0

Can someone help me to resolve this issue

Comment: I see you're calling the `fs` module twice. Maybe it's because of that point that you get this error (not sure honestly), but you can avoid that by importing everything you want in one line like `import * as fs from 'fs'` and then call `fs.readFileSync` normally.