# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' when using Webpack and PixiJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, fs, pixi.js

I want to create a JavaScript function with which I can specify a path to a folder and load each of the files in that folder into PixiJS, without having to know the name and extension of each of those files. It seems like the fs module in Node.js is the thing to use here.

When I use `import * as fs from 'fs';` at the top of my `game.ts` file, I get this error:

```
ERROR in ./src/my-subproject/game.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\me\WebDev\MyProject\src\my-subproject'
 @ ./src/my-subproject/game.ts 33:24-37
 @ multi ./src/my-subproject/game.ts
```

[This thread](https://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/39819-load-all-assets-in-a-folder/) seems possibly relevant to my situation. It says it won't work because it's "web and not a local file system." What does this mean? If I really can't access my asset files for whatever reason, how is PixiJS able to load them when I give it the file paths?

If that's not the problem, I think it might be an issue with my Webpack. I've seen many different suggestions for modifying my Webpack online and none of them worked for me. For instance,

- https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/requiring-modules-in-node-js-everything-you-need-to-know-e7fbd119be8/
- https://github.com/pugjs/pug-loader/issues/8
- [Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' when using readFileSync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60629293/module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-fs-when-using-readfilesync)

This is my complete webpack.config.js file:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: [
    path.resolve('src/my-subproject', 'game.ts')
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve('dist'),
    filename: 'game-bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: '/node_modules/',
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: [
            ['@babel/preset-env', {
              useBuiltIns: 'usage',
              targets: {
                "chrome": "61",
              }
            }]
          ]
        }
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.txs', '.ts', '.js'],
    modules: [
      path.resolve('src'),
      'node_modules'
    ]
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    port: 8000,
    open: true,
    contentBase: path.resolve('dist'),
    watchContentBase: true
  }
};
```

If I do need to add something to webpack.config.js, could you specify where exactly I should put it? Most sources are unclear about that. Thanks!